# Need a better way than WHERE EXISTS when 0 rows are selected

Tags: sql, performance, where-clause, exists

We have a SQL that updates millions of records. We use WHERE EXISTS to handle when 0 rows are selected. 
My question is there an other way to handle this issue to gain performance.? Or is this the best way. I tried merge, the explain plan looks good but its taking more time than update though.

```
UPDATE /*+ parallel (a, 8) */
      SCH1.TAB1 a
   SET (age,
        dc_requested,
        ppt_qty,
        sol1_indic) =
          (SELECT age,
                  dc_requested,
                  ppt_qty,
                  sol1_indic
             FROM SCH2.TAB2 b
            WHERE     b.ip = a.ip
                  AND a.age IS NULL
                  AND (b.optype = 'P1' OR b.optype = 'P12'))
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM SCH2.TAB2 b2
            WHERE     b2.ip = a.ip
                  AND a.age IS NULL
                  AND (b2.optype = 'P1' OR b2.optype = 'P12'));
```

Comment: `WHERE u.ip = i.ip` What is u? what is i ?

Comment: Does this query compile? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: Aha, he fixed it. @user3570198  Why do you choose such an awkward way of updating kust four fields?

Comment: My bad, it's a typo. I'm so sorry.

Comment: There are 26 columns I simplified the SQL so that its easy to read. I changed nothing else the structure is the same

Comment: You alseo changed the b2 correlation name; it now points to precisely the same table reference (but a different RTE) as b.

Comment: @wildplasser yes, I'm working on oracle DB and I ran the statement as it is and I get the following error. I have the ; and braces in place but still i get this error, so i'm wondering if the structure is right. Can you please check the sql and let me know. Error at line 1
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Script Terminated on line 1.

Comment: Not clear. What did you change? The first time it worked (except for the typos) Now you changed something and it does not work anymore. As I said: you don't need the `WHERE EXISTS(...)` (it only duplicates the join condition) and the `AND a.age IS NULL` can be pulled out to the outer level.

Comment: I ran the exact statement. UPDATE /*+ parallel (a, 8) */
      SCH1.TAB1 a
SET age = b.age
        , dc_requested = b.dc_requested
        , ppt_qty = b.ppt_qty
        , sol1_indic = b.sol1_indic
FROM SCH2.TAB2 b
WHERE b.ip = a.ip
AND a.age IS NULL
AND b.optype IN ('P1' , 'P12')
        ;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra EXISTS clause (it just tests wether a row will be updated)

```
UPDATE /*+ parallel (a, 8) */
      SCH1.TAB1 a
SET age = b.age
        , dc_requested = b.dc_requested
        , ppt_qty = b.ppt_qty
        , sol1_indic = b.sol1_indic
FROM SCH2.TAB2 b
WHERE b.ip = a.ip
AND a.age IS NULL
AND b.optype IN ('P1' , 'P12')
        ;
```

NOTE: this is Postgres's syntax for `UPDATE` (resembling Oracle's) . Other platforms will need slightly different syntax for `UPDATE`.

---

UPDATE: (attempting to preserve the original syntax dialect)

```
UPDATE /*+ parallel (a, 8) */
      SCH1.TAB1 a
   SET (age, dc_requested, ppt_qty, sol1_indic) 
        = (SELECT age, dc_requested, ppt_qty, sol1_indic
             FROM SCH2.TAB2 b
            WHERE b.ip = a.ip
              AND (b.optype = 'P1' OR b.optype = 'P12')
          )
WHERE a.age IS NULL
        ;
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue as the original update is running fine and I rollbacked to note the run time but the updated statement
 UPDATE /*+ parallel (a, 8) */
      SCH1.TAB1 a
   SET (age, dc_requested, ppt_qty, sol1_indic) 
        = (SELECT age, dc_requested, ppt_qty, sol1_indic
             FROM SCH2.TAB2 b
            WHERE b.ip = a.ip
              AND (b.optype = 'P1' OR b.optype = 'P12')
          )
WHERE a.age IS NULL
        ;
is throwing an error ORA-01407: cannot update ("SCH1"."TAB1"."ppt_qty") to NULL. To my understanding the resultset of the select isn't the same